# Android Development tools running on on laptop with 1 gb RAM

Tags: android

Good Day everyone. I have a laptop that has just 1GB of RAM and I am tying to develop android apps. I would like to know if I can run my apps using this laptop. ALso, what kind of profiles would I create for the Android Virtual Device settings. Thanks, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would think it will be terribly slow, if you can run it at all. The OS itself consumes a lot of memory and 1GB is pretty low to run your Eclipse or other tools on top of your operating system. I used to have a windows XP Laptop with 3GB RAM. The emulator would be ready after 10 minutes - once I start it!! I am not a big fan of mac, but had to buy a high end mac book to be able to work faster.

Comment: Thanks alot. Please would increasing my RAM help? If no, is there an alternative development tool that I can use?

Comment: Yes, more RAM would help. A lot. For reference, 1GB is the [_minimum_ requirement for (32-bit) Windows 7](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/products/system-requirements). 64-bit Win7 requires 2GB, and I would say that 4-8GB is the standard these days.

Comment: I'm developing on a 1GB RAM MSI Wind U160, I'm running Ubuntu 13.10 and Eclipse ADT/CDT. It works very good, except Virtual Devices do not load (they do, but it takes ~30minutes), but i use usb debugging.
I have no issues even on projects with >200k lines of code

Comment: Thanx alot @Kushal, Tanis and Minsonic.

Comment: @Mndsonic. Can you please tell me the properties of your virtual device? i.e Platform, Target device, CPU, memory options e.t.c